# Removing domain from sql query results

Tags: sql

Say I use the command [MYSQL]:

```
Select Username, UserType from USERS_DATABASE;
```

And i get the next results:

```
Username:            UserType:         
someDomain/user1      User
someDomain/user2      User
diffDomain/user3      User
```

Is there any way i can remove the domain through an SQL query or I need to parse it and then remove?

The domains can be different (Length, Characters and so on)

Thanks.

Comment: What database is this for?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SQL Server

```
Select substring(Username,charindex('/',Username)+1,len(Username)) as Username, 
UserType 
from USERS_DATABASE;
```

In MySQL

```
Select substring(Username,locate('/',Username)+1,length(Username)) as Username, 
UserType 
from USERS_DATABASE;
```

Comment: I think the user wants to remove the domain name while your query will remove the User Names

Comment: Yes. Edited it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming T-SQL you can use this:-

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Username, CHARINDEX('/', Username) + 1, LEN(Username)), UserType
FROM USERS_DATABASE;
```